# What are Motivic homotopy types?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, motives, motivic-homotopy

There are suggestions that says that Grothendieck developed (in some sense) a theory of Motivic homotopy types or at least named it.

I would like to know the reference in which Grothendieck did it, and some references on subsequently development.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure about later developments, but the idea is mentioned in a famous passage of Grothendieck's *Récoltes et Semailles*. I quote from Roy Lisker's translation:

> Thus, the motive presents itself as the deepest "form invariant" which
>   one has been able to associate up to the present moment with an
>   algebraic variety, setting aside its "motivic fundamental group". For
>   me both invariants represent the "shadows" projected by a "**motivic
>   homotopy type**" which remains to be discovered (and about which I say
>   a few things in the footnote: "The tower of scaffoldings- or tools and
>   vision" (R&S IV, #178, see scafolding 5 (Motives), and in particular
>   page 1214)).
>
> It is the latter object which appears to me to be the most perfect
>   incarnation of the elusive intuition of "arithmetic form" ( or
>   "motivic"), of an arbitrary algebraic variety.